# Receive data from xbee into c++

Tags: c++, xbee

I have connected a transmitter to a CAN bus and want to receive the raw data into a c++ program using Xbee. I want to know what I need to do in order to make this happen?

My expected results is to receive serial data from the device.

Comment: Xbee receiver to Arduino to USB port of pc, read the serial data.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I used windows forms - CLR project to create a GUI that opens the serial port. It seems to be able to read the com port once the receiver is attached to the USB port.